# Maven suddenly wants src/ instead of src/main/java

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I'm using Maven 3.3.3 together with Eclipse Mars and m2e. Yesterday, I created a new Java project and converted it into a Maven one.

Afterwards, the classpath contained only `src` instead of the standard `src/main/java`. I was surprised but I simply created the missing folders and ran m2e's "Update Project". This didn't solve the problem; m2e still insisted on using only `src`.

So I edited the classpath manually to end up with with the usual

```
src/test/java
src/test/resources
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

When I try m2e's "Update Project" now, I get this error:

```
Cannot nest 'foo/src/test/java' inside 'foo/src'. To enable the nesting, exclude 'test/' from 'foo/src'
```

*sigh* I went to the command line next and ran `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to get this classpath:

```
src/test/java
src/test/resources
src
src/main/resources
```

Now, I'm completely stumped. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 45):

Open your POM in the POM editor and click on the "Effective POM" tab. Search for `sourceDirectory`. You'll probably see something like this:

```
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
```

When you first converted the Java project to Maven, m2e tried to keep the classpath the same. Eclipse Java projects have a different layout by default. They use `src/` instead of `src/main/java/`. There is no test folder since Eclipse projects usually put their tests into a different project.

To fix the issue:

1. Delete the `sourceDirectory` element from the POM (Note: It might be in a parent POM).
2. Go to the project
3. Select all the source folders
4. Remove them from the build path (context menu -> Build Path -> Remove From Build Path).
5. Update the project

The error should now be gone and the classpath should be correct.

Comment: @turboemu If you do that, then the problem will be back, eventually.

Comment: @JohnnyBigoode Because this config option tells Eclipse what the source folder should be.

Comment: @AaronDigulla just because I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed, the pom.xml will actually tell Eclipse how to configure the build path? That's actually really smart, and it solves a LOT of issues I currently have with Eclipse.

Comment: The m2e plugin can read POM files and it will configure Eclipse to its best of abilities. There are some differences between Maven and Eclipse which the plugin can't emulate like Maven having two classpaths (compile and test) and code in `src/test/java` being able to see code in `src/main/java` but not the other way around.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Not sure how but it worked. I skipped the step 1 as xml under Effective Pom tab was not editable.

Comment: @Manish That's correct; the Effective Pom just tells you what Maven sees after gathering all the bits and pieces. You need to understand yourself where they come from and then edit the source yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are two types of folders that you can create: 1) Package 2) Source Folder

1) A package looks like this
[image]

To create a package, right click on the folder you want (in my example, I right clicked on Java Resources) --> New --> Package

[image]

A pop up window that looks like this should appear

[image]

“Source folder:” That is where you choose your project. If you don’t see anything there, click on “Browse…” and find your project. If I click “Browse…” it shows this:

“Name:” is the name you will give your package.

[image]

**Note: Packages should be within Source Folders. Source Folders are the parent folder.**

2) Source Folders look like this:
[image]

To create a Source Folder, right click on the folder you want (in my example, I right clicked on Java Resources) --> New --> Source Folder

[image]

Under “Project name:” write your project’s name. If you need help, click “Browse…”

Under “Folder name:” write the folder name you want.

Error: If you’re trying to create a “src/main/resources” folder and you’re running into this error “Cannot nest ‘ProjectName’ inside ‘ProjectName’. To enable the nesting exclude ‘main/’ from

[image]

Solution:

[image: --Pic 8--]

Comment: This one works for me, but I had to rename the src folder first and then copy all its content to the new SOURCE FOLDER created.